# ResetDC() does nothing (print spooler API's for Windows)

Tags: windows, delphi, printing, spooler, printer-properties

I've written wrapper classes for [Windows' print spooler APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which work... mostly.

The only thing that does **not** work is **applying printer settings**.

First I call [DocumentProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to successfully acquire and play with printer settings.

Then I try to apply those settings using [ResetDC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162925%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) but nothing happens.
The function takes a valid handle, and returns the same valid handle, meaning it should have applied the settings.
But, nothing seems to have happened:  the printouts are unaffected by the changes in printer settings.

I've even tried to use [SetPrinter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [level 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), also without effect.

This task is getting fairly urgent.  Any suggestions?

Using Delphi XE2, Windows 7 64-bit.

---

Okay, skip all the bulk of the big OO wrappers.  Here's a condensed procedural version.  (Note that you must give it an XPS file.)

Printer settings changes **are being applied** (when using Info2_Apply()) and can be seen in MS Word.
They're just being **ignored when printing**.  That's the mystery.

I've tried so many things that I'm running out of options.  Help would be.... extremely much appreciated.

---

I've finally run out of options.

Here's the last version of my test code.  It's self contained and contains more functions than you need - a consequence of desperately trying anything I could think of.

If anyone else can get printer settings to work, could you please let me know?

Populate a combo box with printer names using:

```
uses
  Printers

ComboBox1.Items.Assign(Printer.Printers);
```

Printing procedure (my test code):

```
uses
  Winapi.WinSpool

procedure PrintXPS(PrinterName, FileNameXPS: string; ParentFormHandle: THandle = 0);

  //  Printer handle

  procedure Printer_Open(out Printer: THandle; Defaults: PPrinterDefaultsW = nil);
  begin
    if  not OpenPrinterW(PWideChar(PrinterName), Printer, Defaults) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  procedure Printer_Close(Printer: THandle);
  begin
    if  not ClosePrinter(Printer) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  //  Printer defaults

  procedure Defaults_Obtain(out DefaultsHandle: THandle; out Defaults: PPrinterDefaultsW);
  begin
    DefaultsHandle  := GlobalAlloc(GHND, SizeOf(TPrinterDefaultsW));
    if  DefaultsHandle = 0  then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    Defaults  := GlobalLock(DefaultsHandle);
    if  Defaults = nil  then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  //  Print settings

  procedure Settings_Obtain(Printer: THandle; out SettingsHandle: THandle; out Settings: PDeviceModeW);
  var
    DeviceModeSize: integer;
  begin
    DeviceModeSize  := DocumentProperties(0, Printer, PWideChar(PrinterName), nil, nil, 0);
    if  DeviceModeSize < 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    //  Allocate memory
    SettingsHandle := GlobalAlloc(GHND, DeviceModeSize);
    if  SettingsHandle = 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    //  Lock memory
    Settings := GlobalLock(SettingsHandle);
    if  Settings = nil then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    //  Populate memory
    if  DocumentProperties(ParentFormHandle, Printer, PWideChar(PrinterName), Settings, Settings, DM_OUT_BUFFER) < 0  then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  procedure Settings_Show(Printer: THandle; var Settings: PDeviceModeW; Options: Cardinal);
  var
    Return: integer;
  begin
    Return  := DocumentProperties(ParentFormHandle, Printer, PWideChar(PrinterName), Settings, Settings, Options);
    if  Return < 0  then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  //  DC

  function  ObtainDC(Printer: THandle; DeviceMode: PDeviceModeW): HDC;
  begin
    Result  := CreateDC(nil, PWideChar(PrinterName), nil, DeviceMode);
    if  Result = 0  then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  procedure ApplyDC(DC: HDC; DeviceMode: PDeviceModeW);
  begin
    if  ResetDC(DC, DeviceMode^) = 0  then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  //  PRINTER_INFO_2

  procedure Info2_Obtain(Printer: THandle; out Info2Handle: THandle; out Info2: PPrinterInfo2W);
  var
    InfoSize: Cardinal;
  begin
    GetPrinterW(Printer, 2, nil, 0, @InfoSize);
    //  Get printer info memory
    Info2Handle := GlobalAlloc(GHND, InfoSize);
    if  Info2Handle = 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    //  Lock printer info memory
    Info2 := GlobalLock(Info2Handle);
    if  Info2 = nil then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    //  Get printer info data
    if  not GetPrinterW(Printer, 2, Info2, InfoSize, @InfoSize)  then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  procedure Info2_Apply(Printer: THandle; Info2: PPrinterInfo2W);
  begin
    if  not SetPrinterW(Printer, 2, Info2, 0) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  //  PRINTER_INFO_8

  procedure Info8_Fetch(Printer: THandle; Settings: PDeviceModeW);
  var
    lBuffer: PPrinterInfo8W;
    lBufferSize: Cardinal;
  begin
    GetPrinterW(Printer, 8, nil, 0, @lBufferSize);
    GetMem(lBuffer, lBufferSize);
    try
      FillChar(lBuffer^, lBufferSize, 0);
      //  Make the call
      lBuffer.pDevMode  := Settings;
      if  not GetPrinterW(Printer, 8, lBuffer, lBufferSize, @lBufferSize) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    finally
      FreeMem(lBuffer, lBufferSize);
    end;
  end;

  procedure Info8_Apply(Printer: THandle; Settings: PDeviceModeW);
  var
    lPrinterInfo8: TPrinterInfo8W;
  begin
    lPrinterInfo8.pDevMode  := Settings;
    if  not SetPrinterW(Printer, 8, @lPrinterInfo8, 0) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  //  PRINTER_INFO_9

  procedure Info9_Fetch(Printer: THandle; Settings: PDeviceModeW);
  var
    lBuffer: PPrinterInfo9W;
    lBufferSize: Cardinal;
  begin
    GetPrinterW(Printer, 9, nil, 0, @lBufferSize);
    GetMem(lBuffer, lBufferSize);
    try
      FillChar(lBuffer^, lBufferSize, 0);
      //  Make the call
      lBuffer.pDevMode  := Settings;
      if  not GetPrinterW(Printer, 9, lBuffer, lBufferSize, @lBufferSize) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    finally
      FreeMem(lBuffer, lBufferSize);
    end;
  end;

  procedure Info9_Apply(Printer: THandle; Settings: PDeviceModeW);
  var
    lPrinterInfo9: TPrinterInfo9W;
  begin
    lPrinterInfo9.pDevMode  := Settings;
    if  not SetPrinterW(Printer, 9, @lPrinterInfo9, 0) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  //  Print jobs

  function  JobCreate(Printer: THandle; FileName: string): Cardinal;
  var
    lBufferSize: Cardinal;
    lAddJobInfo: PAddJobInfo1W;
  begin
    //  Create job
    AddJobW(Printer, 1, nil, 0, lBufferSize);
    GetMem(lAddJobInfo, lBufferSize);
    try
      if  not AddJobW(Printer, 1, lAddJobInfo, lBufferSize, lBufferSize)  then
        RaiseLastOSError;
      Result  := lAddJobInfo.JobId;
      //  Copy the file into place
      CopyFile(PWideChar(FileName), lAddJobInfo.Path, True);
    finally
      FreeMem(lAddJobInfo, lBufferSize);
    end;
  end;

  procedure JobStart(Printer: THandle; JobID: Cardinal);
  begin
    if  not ScheduleJob(Printer, JobID) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  //  General cleanup

  procedure ReleaseHandle(Handle: THandle);
  begin
    if  not GlobalUnlock(Handle)  then
      ;//RaiseLastOSError;
    if  GlobalFree(Handle) <> 0 then
      ;//RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

var
  PrinterA{, PrinterB}: THandle;
  Defaults: PPrinterDefaultsW;
  DefaultsHandle: THandle;
  DataType: string;
  Settings: PDeviceModeW;
  SettingsHandle: THandle;
  Info2: PPrinterInfo2W;
  Info2Handle: THandle;
//  DC: HDC;
  JobID: Cardinal;
begin
  if  not FileExists(FileNameXPS)  then
    raise Exception.Create('File not found: ' + FileNameXPS);

  //  Get DataType
  Printer_Open(PrinterA);
  try
    Info2_Obtain(PrinterA, Info2Handle, Info2);
    try
      DataType  := WideCharToString(Info2.pDatatype);
    finally
      ReleaseHandle(Info2Handle);
    end;
  finally
    Printer_Close(PrinterA);
  end;

  Defaults_Obtain(DefaultsHandle, Defaults);
  try
    Defaults.pDatatype      := PWideChar(DataType);
    Defaults.pDevMode       := nil;
    Defaults.DesiredAccess  := PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS;

    Printer_Open(PrinterA, Defaults);
    try
      Info2_Obtain(PrinterA, Info2Handle, Info2);
      try
        Settings_Show(PrinterA, Info2.pDevMode, DM_IN_BUFFER or DM_IN_PROMPT or DM_OUT_BUFFER);
        //  Try according to:
        //  - Remarks section in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        //  - Comment on code line 246 in http://www.lessanvaezi.com/changing-printer-settings-using-the-windows-api/
        Info2.pSecurityDescriptor := nil;
        Info2_Apply(PrinterA, Info2);

        JobID := JobCreate(PrinterA, FileNameXPS);
        JobStart(PrinterA, JobID);

      finally
        ReleaseHandle(Info2Handle);
      end;
    finally
      Printer_Close(PrinterA);
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseHandle(DefaultsHandle);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Is this link [How can I set a printer settings?](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0020.htm) of any help? Otherwise please submit some code that exemplifies your problems.

Comment: We'll need some code to reproduce the issue. What is the content of your DEVMODE structure, for instance?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added an "Answer" rather then editing the original question.  I'm not sure that's the best way, but I'm new to this forum format.

Comment: If you have the correct answer it is perfectly valid to put that as an answer, otherwise if you want to add more input to the question, edit the question as BillTheLizard helped you with.

Comment: The problem, I presume, is you are not using the DC you updated, `ResetDC` is clear about `hdc` :*"Handle to the DC to update"*, but you're deleting it as soon as you've updated it. If I call for instance 'StartDoc' before deleting the DC, I can see in the queue window a job with updated DevMode. I have no idea how/if it would be possible to use a DC with `AddJob`.

Comment: Thanks @Sertac Akyuz for spotting that.  Still no effect though. I've updated the code sample.

Comment: @Peter - What I'm thinking is that the print job is not using the DC you modified at all. You pass a DC to StartPage, StartDoc etc., maybe that's what ResetDC is for..

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz - You're probably right, but even without using DC, it doesn't work.